# Trace norm of rank one operator $x\otimes y$ for $x,y\in H$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, trace, orthonormal

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. The trace norm on $B(H)$ is defined as 
$$\|u\|_{1}:=\operatorname{tr}(|u|):=\sum_{e\in E}\langle|u|(e),e\rangle,$$
where $|u|:=(u^{*}u)^{1/2}$ and $E$ is (any) orthonormal basis for $H$. This may be $+\infty$. It can be shown that this definition is independent of $E$. For $x,y\in H$ we have a rank one operator $x\otimes y\colon H\to H$ defined by $(x\otimes y)(h):=\langle h, y\rangle x$. I want to show that $\|x\otimes y\|_{1}=\|x\|\|y\|$. I have computed 
$$(x\otimes y)^{*}(x\otimes y)=\|x\|^{2}(y\otimes y).$$
So if $y\neq0$, then
$$(x\otimes y)^{*}(x\otimes y)=\|x\|^{2}\|y\|^{2}(u\otimes u),\quad\text{where}\quad u:=y/\|y\|.$$
But how do I proceed? I think that I have to pick a specific orthonormal basis $E$, but I don't see how. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $|u|$ is defined to be the unique positive operator for which $|u|^2 = u^*u$. Thus, with your work so far, we can now deduce that 
$$
|x \otimes y| = \|x\|\,\|y\|\,u \otimes u.
$$
Now, the easiest way to compute $\operatorname{tr}(|x\otimes y|)$ is to select an orthonormal basis $E$ whose first element is $u$.  For the purposes of your proof/computation, it suffices to note that such an orthonormal basis necessarily exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you elaborate on the computation of $\|x\otimes y\|_{1}$ after I picked such a basis $E$ that contains $u$?

Comment: @Calculix If $E$ is an orthonormal basis containing $u$, and $e\in E$ with $e\neq u$, then $|x\otimes y|(e)=0$.  Thus the sum reduces drastically.